# System.debug giving error

Tags: salesforce, apex

```
public class Json_Callout{
    public static string response;  
    // Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
    public static string getContent() {
        system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++In side the Method Get Content');
        String url = 'http://180.211.69.30:8080/JhImpl/WS/implService/upload';
        // Instantiate a new http object
        Http h = new Http();
        try {
            system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++In side the Try Block');
            // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setHeader('abc', 'abc');
            req.setEndpoint(url);
            req.setMethod('GET');

            // Send the request, and return a response
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            system.debug('Result==========================================='+res);
            system.debug('REsult for Variable=============================='+res.getBody());

            response = res.getStatus();
            String contact = response;
            return res.getBody();
        }
        catch(System.CalloutException ex) {
            system.debug('catch'+ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Getting Error in the Last `System.debug()` statement. Error is that:

> Non-void method might not return a value or might have a statement after the return statement.

How do i fix it?

Also how do i access the response object in Salesforce Page and Parse the object.

Trying to access it with apex:variable but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a string. If you catch an exception you will still need to return something or throw an exception of your own.

Add something like

```
return '';
```

Or

```
return null;
```

As the last line in the method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that last line should be:

```
system.debug('catch'+ex.getMessage());
```

getMessage() is available for any class inheriting from "exception".